# SSH using putty : Network error connection timeout

Tags: server, 20.04, ssh, openssh, putty

i am using Ubuntu server 20.04 lts i have configured static IP and can ping google.com and i can also ping server from another computer vice-versa. my ssh status is active and port 22 is listening but when i try to connect through putty using SSH putty pops error of  Network error connection timeout

Answer (score 0):

ssh service for Ubuntu is sshd, you can check if it's actually running by typing sudo systemctl status sshd, if sshd it's up then try modifying your firewall rules, as long as I remember Ubuntu comes with ufw by default so I will make some assumptions here:

**let's  say sshd isn't installed, then sudo apt-get install sshd.**

**Try this for testing firewall:**
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
Now try to ssh into your server, if it works then remove the iptables entry.

Personally I prefer firewalld because that's the firewall I use daily if you want to use it install it with sudo apt-get remove ufw && sudo apt-get install firewalld

**After installing firewalld assuming your nic (ethernet interface) is eth0 move it to public, considering that this is a server and security matters:**
sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --add-interface=eth0

**Not recommended** add ssh service for this interface: sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --add-service=ssh (if you do this you will receive a lot of traffic coming from people trying to enter your server)

**Now let's say you have an static ip** if you use an static ip on your personal computer then you can add that ip to a whitelist, there are many ways to do this but I will tell you my favorite
sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --direct --add-rule ipv4 filter INPUT 0 -p tcp --dport 22 --src MY-STATIC-IP -j ACCEPT
If you have any problem let me know and I hope this help you!!!